# how to use isset for password

Tags: php, post, if-statement, passwords, isset

I'm giving this simple html form with password and with php I'm giving to do this

The only valid password shall be "testing" (without the quotes). If the user did not type a password, give them a warning to "Please type a password" and do no more processing on the data at all. If the user did not type the valid password "testing" (without the quotes), then tell the user "Invalid password, sorry" and do no more processing on the data at all. (Use an “if” statement to find out if they entered a password, etc…)

but I just can't seem to figure out
can someone give me a hand?

the html coding is

```
<form action = "lab.php" method = "post" name = "lab_form">
what is your last name: <input type = "text" name = "last"><br />
what is your student number (password): <input type = "password" name = "number">
</form>
```

what I did with my php is this....but didn't work at all...and all I've learned is $_POST and isset for now.  I wonder how I can get this done with $_POST, isset and with if statement...

```
<?php
echo $_POST["last"] . "<br/>"; 

if (isset($_POST["number"]))
{
    echo "The variable $_POST[number] exists.";
}
else if (!(isset($_POST["number"])))
{
    echo "Please enter a password.";
}
else
{
    echo "No variable called $_POST[number]";
}
?>
```

I know what I'm doing wouldn't make must sense....but...ya :(

Thanks in advance though ^_^

P.S.  I know in the php code I should add something like

```
if($_POST["number"] == testing)
```

and continuing on but the thing is I couldn't even make it show the other parts so i didn't bother try the "testing" as password yet.

Answer (score 1):

Small mistake. Use `empty()` too.

```
<?php
echo $_POST["last"] . "<br/>"; 

if (isset($_POST["number"]))
{
    echo "The variable $_POST[number] exists.";
}
elseif (empty($_POST["number"]))
{
    echo "Please enter a password.";
}
elseif (!isset($_POST["number"]))
{
    echo "No variable called $_POST[number]";
}
?>
```

Comment: ah ok...I did that and switched the !isset to top seems to work better but I'm told to "if the user did not type a password, give them a warning to "Please type a password" and do no more processing on the data at all" How can I do that though?

Comment: because if I press submit it still goes to the next page though.  Just that the next page will say Please enter a password. Actually the form doesn't only have two lines to fill out there are like 3-4 more lines of random things after the password but even with empty I will still see the rest of the data in the form being processed.

Comment: `echo "No variable called $_POST[number]";` would return `Notice: Undefined index: number`, you either have to escape $ (`echo "No variable called \$_POST[number]";`) or use ' (`echo 'No variable called $_POST[number]';`)